# Firebase Database and Python, How do I use .replace() to replace Space with Newline

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a new face to firebase-database, I'm using it for having an interface to the results of my mobile app. So in short I have to take some values from the database. I used the python-firebase package and I manage to get this input from my structure.

Scan-in : Nov 29, 2017 64035 PM Checklist Coffee tray with 3 coffee sticks, 3 creamer, 3 white sugar, 3 brown sugar, 1 equal or sweetener, 3 lipton tea, 2 mineral water, 3 cocktail napkin ? :No Luggage bench fabric top is clean :No 1 facial tissue in a tissue box :No Towel Reminder :No 1 pringles, 1 cashew nut, 1 cup noodles (placed in the coffee tray on the writing desk)? :No Curtains are neat, presentable with hooks all intact and curtain rod :No Drawers \u2013 clean and dust-free :No ... 
and so on

Actually this output has u,' and other unrelated text that came from the database when I fetched it. However I cleaned it up to that point by using replace like this:

```
 result1 = result1.replace("u'", "")
    result1 = result1.replace("{", "")
    result1 = result1.replace("}", "")
    result1 = result1.replace("'", "")
    result1 = result1.replace(":", "")
```

however I wanted to repalce the space after each "Yes/No" with a new line. So i tried this

```
    result1 = result1.replace("No,", ":No\n")
    result1 = result1.replace("Yes,", ":Yes\n")
```

and this:

```
    result1 = result1.replace("No,", ":No<br/>")
    result1 = result1.replace("Yes,", ":Yes<br/>")
```

the first one didn't work and the second but tons of br's on my text.

How am I supposed to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Here's my sample full code:

```
@app.route("/room1")
def room1():



    result1 = firebase.get('/Rooms/Room1/2017-11-29/Inspection/Scan-in/Inspector/trhf/', None)
    result1 = str(result1)
    print result1
    result2 = firebase.get('/Rooms/Room1/2017-11-29/Inspection/Scan-out/Inspector/', None)
    result2 = str(result2)
    print result2

    result1 = result1.replace("u'", "")
    result1 = result1.replace("{", "")
    result1 = result1.replace("}", "")
    result1 = result1.replace("'", "")
    result1 = result1.replace(":", "")
    result1 = result1.replace("No,", ":No\n")
    result1 = result1.replace("Yes,", ":Yes\n")
    result2 = result2.replace("u'", "")
    result2 = result2.replace("{", "")
    result2 = result2.replace("}", "")
    result2 = result2.replace("'", "")
    result2 = result2.replace("Time: " + result1, "")
    result2 = result2.replace(":", "")





    return render_template('new.html', result2=result2, result1=result1)
```

Here's my database structure:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: that library is deprecated, you should have used pyrebase instead check this library https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase

Answer (score 0):

```
result1 = result1.replace("No,", ":No\n")
result1 = result1.replace("Yes,", ":Yes\n")
```

Not sure why you have commas in there if you're trying to replace spaces.  It should just be:

```
result1 = result1.replace("No ", ":No\n")
result1 = result1.replace("Yes ", ":Yes\n")
```